# CSS .hover on tr with the first TD having rowspan in Chrome

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with the format like this:

TR -> TD rowspan=2 -> TD -> TD

TR ->              -> TD -> TD

TR -> TD rowspan=2 -> TD -> TD

TR ->              -> TD -> TD

Repeats........

On hover of any TD, the TR is highlighted and the TD with Rowspan is highlighted in full if a TD in either row is highlighted.

Like this:

[image]

When moving down the table the CSS is applied / removed properly. However whn moving UP the table the CSS is not removed from the bottom half of the TD with the rowspan

Example:

[image]

**This only happens in chrome;**

Currently my only CSS is

```
.hover{
    background-color: #1797C0 !important;
}
```

The JS is This:

```
                $("[id$=user_data] td").hover(function() {

                  $el = $(this);

                  $el.parent().addClass("hover");

                  if ($el.parent().has('td[rowspan]').length == 0)

                    $el
                      .parent()
                      .prevAll('tr:has(td[rowspan]):first')
                      .find('td[rowspan]')
                      .addClass("hover");

                }, function() { 

                  $el
                    .parent()
                    .removeClass("hover")
                    .prevAll('tr:has(td[rowspan]):first')
                    .find('td[rowspan]')
                    .removeClass("hover");

                });
```

Is there something in Chrome that causes the color to remain when the TR/TD is no longer hover? Using developer tool the TD does NOT have the class .hover yet the color remains.

So my question is:

Where in my JS is the CSS background color not being reset for the part of the TD that is on the second row of the rowSpan

I would like it to highlight the entire first cell (with rowspan) and the rest of row 1 when hovering on a td in row 1. Highlight the entire TD in Row 1 col 1 when hovering in any TD in row 2

repeat for rows 3-4 and 5-6 and so on, removing the highlight from the previous rows/td(s).

Regardless of moving up or down in the Table

It currently works in Safari and Firefox but Chrome is keeping the Highlight in the bottom of the TD with the rowspan only when moving UP in the table.

Comment: Have you tried this on a different version of Chrome?

Comment: I have tried on Chrome for Mac and Windows. Not sure of the version numbers at this time.

Comment: That is not JavaScript, that is jQuery. I'm officially done with this question as I don't use frameworks. You need to reword your question and you need to not only remove the JavaScript altogether from this you also need to weed out any frameworks that add unnecessary dependencies and over-complicate your code.

Comment: Sorry I am not as almighty as you. I rely on JQuery a lot due to the environment I work in. Makes life a whole lots easier. Also in this case regardless of if I use query or pure JS there should be no major difference. It is just selectors and adding a class after all. I appreciate your comments but they come of a bit pretentious. All I am asking for is some help getting the issue with Chrome resolved. To date nothing you have said has been any help but rather critique that I am using query. I guess I am not good enough for this site so sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well. This is my port of that jquery code to native JS.
Hope it helps =)

```
(function () {

    function findRowSpan(element) {
        var sibling = element;
        var rowspanFound = false;

        var rowSpanCols = [];

        while (!rowspanFound) {

            var cols = sibling.getElementsByTagName("td");
            for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
                var col = cols[i];
                if (col.hasAttribute('rowspan')) {
                    rowSpanCols.push(col);
                }
            }
            rowspanFound = rowSpanCols.length > 0;
            sibling = sibling.previousElementSibling;
        }
        return rowSpanCols;

    }

    function doForAll(array,func) {
        for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            var item = array[j];
            func(item);
        }
    }

    function rowSpanHover(element,func) {
        var parent = element.parentNode;
        func(parent);

        var cols = findRowSpan(parent);
        doForAll(cols, function (col) {
            func(col);
        });
    }

    function addClass(element,cssClass) {
        element.className = element.className +" "+ cssClass;
    }

    function removeClass(element, cssClass) {
        element.className = element.className.replace(cssClass, "").trim();
    }

    return {

        setup: function () {
            var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

            for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
                var cell = cells[i];

                cell.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
                    rowSpanHover(this, function(element) {
                        addClass(element, "hover");
                    });
                });

                cell.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
                    rowSpanHover(this, function (element) {
                        removeClass(element, "hover");
                    });

                });
            }
        }
    };
})();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I added a $.each(this.cells, function(){
          func(col);
      }); in the function to capture the rest of the TD in the TR and all is good. You went above and beyond. Not only did you confirm that it was a chrome only issue but you provided the solution. I found that when applying CSS using jquery the TD's I saw the same issue even with your code. Using the each loop inside of your code did not cause the issue. Again, thank you very much.